# Set length to either 0 or 2 using regular expression for special character

Tags: java, regex

How to set special character length is either 0 or 2 in regular expression JAVA.
I used the following but it returns false

```
([$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-// ]{0,2})
```

Comment: Can you also show us some sample input against which you plan to run your regex?  Are you testing for presence of either 0 or 2 _total_ metacharacters, or do they need to be adjacent?

Comment: You can test your inputs using regex tools available online.

Comment: This Is my expression can you tell me where is the issue why it return false when I put same pattern as expression 
[0-9a-zA-Z])*([01]{2})+\\w+([a-zA-Z0-9_]{22})+\\w+(^([$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-// ]{2}|))+\\w+([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})